# Highcharts export functionality is not working

Tags: highcharts, requirejs, highcharts-ng

Highcharts export functionality is not working if I use requirejs  to load all the files of my angular project.

Let me know if any thing I am missing

thanks a lot in advanced

Comment: exporting.js is included, right?

Comment: Yes.. actually, the problem is exporting.js .. this is condition is failing if I load all the files using requireJS,


`typeof module==="object"&&module.exports?module.exports=f:f(Highcharts)})`,
      

Note: its working fine if I don't use requireJS to load all the files.

Comment: Probably the problem is that exporing.js is loaded asynchronisly and stop working. Can you force to load it sync, after highcharts.js loading ?

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan. thanks a lot for quick replay.. as I have already mention in my above comment .. beacuse of the "If condition" its not going inside of the function f(Highchats)

Comment: @SebastianBochan ., I am using webpack packaging node module and require js for loading my all the files.