# Highcharts exporting functionality not working in latest release

Tags: highcharts, export, aurelia

We are developing a SPA with charting features using Highcharts. We are using Highcharts version 4.2.3 installed using npm/jspm with Aurelia framework.

We are facing issues with "exporting" functionality in Highcharts. It is not showing the "Print" options at all. We are including both core highcharts and highcharts/modules/exporting.

We do see both highcharts.js and exporting.js loading just fine.

Also, We came across this thread which looks exactly the issue we are facing. Do we have a solution for this?

[Highcharts export functionality is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784606/highcharts-export-functionality-is-not-working)

I am positive that Aurelia is using requirejs to load all the dependencies.

Thanks
Senthil S

Answer (score 1):

It has changed the way it is loading the modules.

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import Exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
Exporting(Highcharts);
```

Please refer to this thread on Highcharts forum.

http://forum.highcharts.com/post127945.html#p127945

Thanks
Senthil S

Answer (score 0):

**Add **

```
global.Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(global.Highcharts);
```

**add these two lines  in top of your component it will  work fine **